# MySQL create table query 1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table video(

    ID int auto_increment,
    title varchar(20),
    country varchar(20),
    producer varchar(20),
    release_date datetime default 0,
    color varchar(5),
    genre varchar(20),

    primary key (ID)

);

create table performer(

    vid_id int,
    perf_id int not null,
    age number(3),
    name varchar(10),
    gender varchar(6),

    primary key (perf_id),
    foreign key (vid_id) references video (ID) 

);
```

The above is the script that I've written to create tables named as **video** and **performer**. When the script is executed, MySQL creates the table video but generates the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'number(3),
name varchar(10),
gender varchar(6),

primary key (perf_id)' at line 4
```

I think the syntax for defining foreign key and primary key is correct but still this error pops up. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Replace number with int,mysql doesnt have number.BUt in general it`s better to store the birth or start or something and then calculate the age on the fly

Comment: Thnaks alot, That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use Oracle database.
In Oracle : number(p,s): A decimal number with up to 38 significant digits in the range of -(10**125) to +(10**125). Where p is the precision and s is the scale.
But in mysql corresponding is Decimal(p, s)

Answer (score 2):

`age number(3)` is incorrect. MySQL does not support `number` format. You can use `tinyint` datatype for storing age.

Example:

```
age tinyint(3) UNSIGNED
```

`UNSIGNED` can store values upto 127.

Reference [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)